# Declaration of a font/change of parameters/compilation error is missing

Tags: pdftex, latex3, compilation-error, texify

I would like to know what in here

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet\stixcalE{LS2}{stixcalE}{m}{n}
```

the parameters

LS2,m and n stand for, and to what values I can correctly change them?

Whenever I type an obviously incorrect value in place of n,
the pdftexify does not complain about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LS2` is the encoding, `stixcalE` the font family, `m` the series (m=\mdseries, bx=\bfseries), `n` the shape (n=\upshape, it= \itshape etc).

There is a fallback system for the last three arguments. E.g. if you use a shape that isn't declared, latex will fall back to n.

Comment: Is `stixcalE` really the font family? The letter `E` is mine there. Isn't  `stixcalE` rather alias? Thank you

Comment: I don't know if your example uses correct names, but the second argument after the LS2 is where you should put the font family name.

Answer (score 1):

The font selection interface is described in detail in "LaTeX2e font selection" (`fntguide.pdf`) which can be found at the LaTex Project website at  https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/ and which is distributed with LaTeX so should be available at your installation too.